# Linking error in C++ Template

Tags: c++, templates, linker

I need to generated a simple Logger (with out third party libs) that's need to be link to dll. Therefore I generated a class with some of his class method were templates, the code compile fine but I get linker error. I am compiling  with MS VS 2008 and gcc-4. The code is:

Log.h class:

```
class MiniLogger
{
private:
   std::ofstream mOutPutFile;
protected:
   void write (std::string const& text);
public:
   ~MiniLogger();
   MiniLogger( std::string const& lName) throw(FileError);
   static MiniLogger* getInstance(std::string const & fName);
   static void destoryInstance(MiniLogger*);

  template<class T>
  MiniLogger& operator<<(T & data);
  MiniLogger& operator<<(std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&) );

};


MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&))
{

   //mOutPutFile << out;
   return *this;
}
template<class T>
MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (T  & data)
{
 //Just try with out calling other method
// write(data);
   return *this;
}
```

At main I instantiated the Object and use it :

```
#include "log.h"

int main()
{


    MiniLogger &a=*(MiniLogger::getInstance("text.txt"));

    a << "text" << std::endl;


return 0;
}
```

I get

```
@ubu11-10-64b-01:~/cplus/template$ g++ main.cpp log.cpp
/tmp/cccMdSBI.o: In function `MiniLogger::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))':
log.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `MiniLogger::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&))'
/tmp/ccj3dfhR.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
```

Comment: Please note that the template code is working just fine; your linker error is in the *non*-template code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined a function in a header file. Since that header file is included in multiple translation units (namely, main.cpp and log.cpp), you've multiply defined the function. (See the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule).)

Either declare the function `inline` and define it in the header file, or declare it `extern` in the header file and define in exactly one source file.

The function in question is: `MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&))`.

Solution #1:

```
// Log.h
inline
MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&))
{
 //mOutPutFile << out;
 return *this;
}
```

Solution #2:

```
// Log.h
extern
MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&));

// Log.cpp
MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (std::ostream& (*func)(std::ostream&))
{
 //mOutPutFile << out;
 return *this;

}
```

---

**Side Note**: Realize that the next entity in the header file, `template<class T>
MiniLogger& MiniLogger::operator<< (T  & data)`, is not a function – it is a function template – and different advice applies to it. As a rule of thumb, you *should* define function templates in header files, but *should not* define functions in header files. (There are exceptions to this rule of thumb.)